# Flutter/ Firestore : Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'document'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have app that I want to retreive data which are messages represented in uid document from Firestore database as explained here and these messages stored like so :
ChatRoom->chatRoomId->chat-> uid-> messages

but I receive this error :

> > The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<dynamic,
> > AsyncSnapshot>#56cb5): Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance
> > getter 'document'. Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot' Tried
> > calling: document
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    StreamBuilder
> file:///Users/ahmedhussain/Downloads/khamsat/Client%20Apps/HPX-KSA/hpx_ksa/lib/Screens/messages.dart:21:12
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
> #1      _MessagesState.chatRoomList. (package:hpxksa/Screens/messages.dart:25:38)

Here is my code:

```
class _MessagesState extends State<Messages> {
  
  Stream chatRoomsStream;

  Widget chatRoomList(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: chatRoomsStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.document.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return ChatRoomTile(
                 username: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["chatRoomId"]
                      .toString().replaceAll("_", "").replaceAll(Constants.myName, "replace"),
                  chatRoomId:snapshot.data.documents[index].data["chatRoomId"]
              );
            }) : Container();
      }
      );
  }

  getUserInfogetChats() {
    DatabaseService().getChatRooms(Constants.myName).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        chatRoomsStream = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserInfogetChats();
    super.initState();
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: chatRoomList(),
    );
  }
}


class ChatRoomTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String username;
  final String chatRoomId;
  ChatRoomTile({this.username, this.chatRoomId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Conversation(chatRoomId: chatRoomId,)));
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black26,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kPrimaryColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
              ),
              child: Text("${username.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()}"),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 8,),
            Text(username),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my get function to retreive chats that contains user name:

```
 getChatRooms(String username)async{
    return await Firestore.instance.collection("ChatRoom").
    where("users", arrayContains: username).
    snapshots();

  }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: this error: Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'document'. Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot' Tried calling: document

Comment: That's not a question. What are you trying to accomplish? The whole question is just an error message and code.

Comment: I am trying to retreive data from from firestore depending on document id

Comment: can you give more clarification about how u structured your data in fire store

Comment: I created ChatRoom collection then a document inside it is created with the name of user1+user2 and another chats collection inside it created which saves the chats in document and the fields are stored in messages

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? Accordingly i can provide solution

Comment: I added the function where I want to get a snapshot of conversations where it contains username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you received is quite clear about what the issue is. `QuerySnapshot` doesn't have a `document` property. You likely intended to use the [`documents`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/documents.html) property, which is more consistent with your attempt to use a `ListView`.

Changing instances of `snapshot.data.document` to `snapshot.data.documents` will solve this particular issue.

Comment: How could it be the exact same error? `document` shouldn't exist anywhere in the code. Please repost this error.

Comment: here is what I have receiveed after changing it to docs : Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'docs'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: docs

Comment: Which package are you using? `cloud_firestore`? or `firebase`?

Comment: Assuming you're using `cloud_firestore`, I have edited my answer. It's a simple typo.

Comment: cloud_firestore

Comment: Thank you man it worked finally. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

```
  return StreamBuilder(
      stream: chatRoomStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ChatRoomTile(
                      **snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['chatRoomId']**);
                },
              )
            : Container();
      },
    );
```

Comment: change "documents" to "docs" and change "data['chatRoomId']" to "data()['chatRoomId']"

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.